# Where can I learn about LineageOS file hierarchy?

Tags: lineageos

I would like to learn more about LineageOS.

I am looking for information that describes data in `/data/` folder.

Especially I am interested in the purpose of the following folders: `user_de`, `user`, `tombstones`, `system_de`, `system_ce`, `system`, `property`, `misc_de`, `misc_ce`, `misc`, `data`, `bcmnfc` and `app`.

Thank you very much for any helpful information!

Comment: Some of them are already explained in [this answer](/a/46934/16575).

Comment: Close voters: This is not necessarily a "development question". See the question linked in my previous comment.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for your link! I understand that this question is too broad, but it gets upvotes, so please are interested. Please leave it for a while open.

Comment: That's why I put my second comment (some people thought it an off-topic develper-only related question, which it is NOT). I still wonder what those "suffixed" folders are (_de, _ce). For system_de/ce, see e.g. [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4bccb46).

Comment: @Izzy I remember Rovo89, the Xposed lead, saying that directories suffixed by `_de` are paths that are left unencrypted, even if the rest of `/data` is encrypted.

Comment: That would be a bit strange – as the link I gave speaks about "sensitive user data" being stored there. But Rovo should know – so if he explicitly stated so, I'd tend to believe that.